Linear Constant Coefficient Differential Equations with the Derivative of the Impulse Function
There is a differential equation in the style of:
$$\sum_{k=0}^N a_k\frac{d^k}{dt^k}y(t) = \sum_{k=0}^M b_k\frac{d^k}{dt^k}x(t)$$
Where $x(t) = \delta(t)$ and we assume $y(t) = 0$ for $t<0$. Particularly, I am having problems with the scenario in which M = 1 and N = 2, where it is easy to find the homogenous solution but I can not extract the initial conditions.
For the case where M = 0, I was taught that the term in the left hand side with the highest order derivative must be $\delta(t)$ since none of the sides had the derivative of $\delta(t)$ in them.
When the right hand side equals $a_0*\delta(t)+a_1*\delta'(t)$ my intuition is that now second highest derivative term in the left hand side should be the impulse function. Then, the highest derivative term will be the derivative of the impulse, and I am left with a discontinuity at the third highest derivative. So I take the integral:
$$\int_{0^-}^{0^+}\sum_{k=0}^2 a_k\frac{d^k}{dt^k}y(t) = \int_{0^-}^{0^+}\sum_{k=0}^1 b_k\frac{d^k}{dt^k}x(t)$$
Shortly for N = 2 and M = 1, and I believe using fundamental theorem of calculus which somehow applies to the impulse function:
$$a_2(\frac{dy(0^+)}{dt}-\frac{dy(0^-)}{dt}) + a_1(y(0^+)-y(0^-)) + \int_{0^-}^{0^+}a_0*y(t)dt = \int_{0^-}^{0^+}b_0*\delta(t)+b_1*\delta'(t)dt$$
Supposing that $y'(t) = A*\delta(t)$, $y(t) = A*u(t)$ and the integral term $\int_{0^-}^{0^+}a_0*y(t)$ evaluates to 0 and also since I put the $y(t<0) = 0$ constraint, I should be left with:
$$a_2\frac{dy(0^+)}{dt}+ a_1 = \int_{0^-}^{0^+}b_0*\delta(t)+b_1*\delta'(t)dt$$
This is where I get stuck. I do not know how to handle the derivative of the delta function inside an integral. I have found in some online forums that its convolution with a function will give the derivative of the function at a time point, but a convolution is an integral from negative infinity to infinity and this information did not help me.
One further question I had about this also relates to the homogenous solution. If the right hand side was just an impulse function, I could safely say it was equal to zero for t>0. Now there is the derivative of the impulse function, which I can't say if it is equal to zero for t > 0.
How can I solve this equation the way I want to, with a form of the solution evaluated to satisfy a set of initial conditions?

Does $$\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} f(t), \delta'(t) , dt=-f'(0),,\quad \epsilon>0$$ provide the insight you need?

Have you investigated the approach of taking the Laplace transforms of both sides of $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^N a_k, \frac{d^k}{dt^k} y(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^M b_k, \frac{d^k}{dt^k} x(t)$$ and then solving for the inverse Laplace transform of $\mathcal{L}_ty(t)$?

@StevenClark yes that would solve the question, I was kind of interested in this approach of a homogoneous solution and its initial values. In regards to your other comment, I am not sure that it does. $b_1$ is just a constant, which makes it derivative zero everywhere. Then this would imply the derivative of the impulse has no effect on the initial conditions, which does not seem true to me?

On the one hand, Mathematica gives a solution which involves the constant $b_1$, so perhaps you're right. On the other hand, I suspect Mathematica derives this solution via the approach in my second comment above which involves integrating $\delta(t)$ and $\delta'(t)$ on the interval $t\in{0,\infty}$ where the result depends on how $\delta(t)$ and $\delta'(t)$ are defined, so I'm a bit suspicious of the result given by Mathematica.
